# Длинная арифметика

Tags: c++, математика, числа, длинная-арифметика

Проверял данный алгоритм на числах до 4 символов, все было нормально. Беру выше, лезут такие вот веселые вещи (умножает он первые два числа): 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот кусок кода:

```
std::vector<char> LongMath::MultIt(std::vector<char> a, std::vector<char> b){
        std::vector<char> result;
        result.resize(maxbits + maxbits - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < maxbits ; i++){
            int carry = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < maxbits; j++){
                result[i + j] += a[i] * b[j] + carry;
                if (result[i] >= 10){
                    carry = result[i + j] / 10;
                    result[i + j] -= carry * 10;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: А как вы выводите?

Comment: @VladD задом наперед

Comment: А всё же, конкретнее.

Comment: `char` небось `signed`?

Comment: Аааа, у вас там только один десятичный разряд?

Comment: @VladD хмм, необходимо поставить unsigned?

Comment: Кстати, вы не сбрасываете carry

Comment: `result[i + j] += a[i] * b[j] + carry; carry = 0;`

Comment: Остальное вроде правильно. Но я бы, конечно, сделал unsigned для порядка. И заассёртил `0 <= a[i] && a[i] <= 9`, на всякий случай.

Comment: @VladD оформите в виде куска кода, пока я сейчас везде потыкуаю unsigned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сбрасывать `carry` после добавления:

```
// передаём как const &, чтобы избежать ненужного копирования
std::vector<char> MultIt(const std::vector<char>& a, const std::vector<char>& b) {
    std::vector<char> result;
    // вычисляем точный размер результата
    result.resize(a.size() + b.size());
    // размер вектора непостоянный, значит, нужно его брать
    // из свойств вектора, а не из константы
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)a.size(); i++) {
        int carry = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < (int)b.size(); j++) {
            // прибавили следующее слагаемое, с учётом старого переноса
            result[i + j] += a[i] * b[j] + carry;
            carry = 0; // обнулили
            if (result[i + j] >= 10) { // нужен ли перенос в следующий разряд?
                carry = result[i + j] / 10;
                result[i + j] -= carry * 10;
            }
        }
        // если остался перенос от предыдущего цикла, нужно добавить и его
        // но при добавлении переноса тоже может возникнуть перенос
        // (например, если мы добавляем 1 к 999), поэтому нужен цикл
        // targetIdx - текущий разряд; цикл пока перенос не нулевой
        for (size_t targetIdx = i + a.size(); carry > 0; targetIdx++)
        {
            result[targetIdx] += carry;
            carry = 0;
            if (result[targetIdx] >= 10) {
                carry = result[targetIdx] / 10;
                result[targetIdx] -= carry * 10;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

И ещё, имеет смысл перейти к `unsigned char`.

Comment: опять же 2-3 символьные числа отлично множит, числа больше 4х знаков он - делает больше вектор, не как необходимо, и половина числа правильная половина неправильная ...

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: Дайте пример чисел

Comment: 8037 7090  - выводит 0560982330 , правильный ответ - 56982330

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: Хм. То есть теперь просто лишние нули?

Comment: именно, может быть дело в шаге?

Comment: Стоп, момент, сейчас.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: А ещё вы один индекс потеряли, обновил ответ, ищу дальше.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: А, ещё у вас теряется carry при окончании внутреннего цикла.

Comment: можете пояснить как идет проверка carry во втором for?

Comment: О, теперь результат правильный вроде :)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: Смотрите. У нас после первого цикла сложения ещё может быть остался перенос. И мы должны его разложить в result. Начинаем с разряда после того, который был последний. На каждом шагу мы прибавляем к текущему разряду carry, и если результат больше 9, вычисляем остаток как обычно, и новый carry, который нужно перенести в следующий разряд. Цикл продолжается до тех пор, пока carry не 0.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: дописал комментарии к коду

Comment: @VladD :-D где-то я уже видел похожие длинные числа

Comment: @Grundy: Точно :)

Answer (score 0):

Переносы не синхронизированы с разрядами результата, надо привязать внешний цикл к этим разрядам. Логика должна поменяться примерно так:

```
    int carry = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxbits+maxbits-2 ; i++){
        result[i] = carry;
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
            result[i] += a[j] * b[i-j];
        }
        if (result[i] >= 10){
            carry = result[i] / 10;
            result[i] -= carry * 10;
        }
    }
    result[maxbits+maxbits-2] = carry;
```

P.S. Ближайшая проблема - в том, что для чисел большой длины переменная carry может оказаться многоразрядной.